# Celery/Django transaction

Tags: django, rabbitmq, celery, django-celery, djcelery

Celery user guides suggests Django transaction be manually committed before calling task process.

http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#database-transactions

I want the system to be as reliable as possible. What is the best practice to recover from a crash between transaction commit and calling task (i.e. make sure task is always called when transaction is committed).

BTW, right now I'm using database-based job queue I implemented so there is no such problem -- I can send jobs within transaction. I'm not really convinced if I should switch to Celery.

Answer (score 0):

From django 1.9 this has been added

```
transaction.on_commit(lambda: add_task_to_the_queue())
```